# align AutoCompleteTextView text position

Tags: android

[image]I am developing a RTL app and want my AutoCompleteTextView widget to display the text from right to left but now it is showing on the left side. i tried doing this in my xml file but no luck.can somebody help me please.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip"
android:gravity="right"> 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cusNameTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/customerName"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/cusName_CB"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok,got it to work.for future reference to other developers. you need to create a TextView. i have saved it as dropdowntext.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dropDown"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

and then in the code you need to add the 4 parameter constructor

```
ArrayAdapter <Customer> customerSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<Customer>(MainMenuActivity.this, R.layout.dropdowntext,R.id.dropDown, customers);
customerTextView.setAdapter(customerSpinner);
```

Answer (score 0):

**dropdowntext.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/text_dropDown"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="right">

</TextView>

final ArrayAdapter<Customer> customerSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<Customer>(MainMenuActivity.this, R.layout.dropdowntext​m, customers);
cusName_CB.setAdapter(AutoCompleteAdapter);
```

Comment: can you please help me with reference to my code,i will appreicate it

Comment: my ArrayAdapter looks like this
    final ArrayAdapter<Customer> customerSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<Customer>(MainMenuActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, customers);

Comment: Just create a new xml file named `dropdowntext.xml` and add the `TextView` code from the answer. Now instead of using `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` while constructing the **Adapter**
, use `R.layout.dropdowntext`

Comment: but my problem is not with the Textview widget but it is withthe Autocompletetextview widget

Comment: also when i try to use your code i get error for the android:background="@color/white"
android:textColor="@color/text_light_grey"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" >

Comment: That's because you don't have those resources in your project...just remove those lines and try. AFAIK what you did was sufficient. But try doing the same for the dropdown too

Comment: i tried your way but my autocomplete features are not working